# Understanding JavaScript for TFS widget

Tags: javascript, tfs, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I've been trying to modify the sample dashboard widget at this location

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/extend/develop/add-dashboard-widget?view=vsts#part-2-hello-world-with-vsts-rest-api

However, reluctantly have to admit I simply can't understand the structure required to extend it

Near the end, it uses "load: function" and returns the outputs of a REST API call, which I can consume however I want

However, I need to make more than one different REST call, and I simply cannot figure out how to get that info usable in my function

I modified the code so it starts like this:

```
VSS.require(["TFS/Dashboards/WidgetHelpers", "TFS/Work/RestClient","VSS/Service", "TFS/WorkItemTracking/RestClient" ],
```

I then created a handle for the other call I want to make like this:

```
var queryClient = VSS_Service.getCollectionClient(TFS_Wit_QueryAPI.WorkItemTrackingHttpClient);

var queryResults = queryClient.getQuery(projectId, "Shared Queries/My Bugs");
```

However, I cannot consume the contents of queryResults - I know it's working up to a point as if I put in an invalid URL it will error as it knows it can't access anything there. If the URL is correct, no matter what I've tried - even `stringify` just to see what comes back - I get 'undefined' or something similar (it's definitely a valid JavaScript object)

The key seems to be right at the end when you have "load: function" except that only allows one thing to be returned? The reason I know this is if I change the function that it returns to be the one I've written rather than the one from the sample, it works fine - but the problem remains the same in that I can only process the results of one API call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call more than one APIs, the code in that article is just the simple sample.

For Widget extension, you just need to return the status (e.g. Success()) in load function, so you can return status at the end of the function. For example:

```
var getQueryInfo = function (widgetSettings) {
                        // Get a WIT client to make REST calls to VSTS
                        return TFS_Wit_WebApi.getClient().getQuery(projectId, "Shared Queries/Feedback")
                            .then(function (query) {
                                // Create a list with query details                                
                                var $list = $('<ul>');
                                $list.append($('<li>').text("Query ID: " + query.id));
                                $list.append($('<li>').text("Query Name: " + query.name));
                                $list.append($('<li>').text("Created By: " + (query.createdBy ? query.createdBy.displayName: "<unknown>") ));

                                // Append the list to the query-info-container
                                var $container = $('#query-info-container');
                                $container.empty();
                                $container.append($list);

                                // Use the widget helper and return success as Widget Status
                                return true;
                            }, function (error) {
                                // Use the widget helper and return failure as Widget Status
                           console.log(error);     
                           return false;
                            });
                    }

var getAnOhterQueryInfo = function (widgetSettings) {
                        // Get a WIT client to make REST calls to VSTS
                        return TFS_Wit_WebApi.getClient().getQuery(projectId, "Shared Queries/Bug")
                            .then(function (query) {
                                // Create a list with query details                                
                                var $list = $('<ul>');
                                $list.append($('<li>').text("Query ID: " + query.id));
                                $list.append($('<li>').text("Query Name: " + query.name));
                                $list.append($('<li>').text("Created By: " + (query.createdBy ? query.createdBy.displayName: "<unknown>") ));

                                // Append the list to the query-info-container
                                var $container = $('#query-info-container');
                                $container.empty();
                                $container.append($list);

                                // Use the widget helper and return success as Widget Status
                                return true;
                            }, function (error) {
                                // Use the widget helper and return failure as Widget Status
                           console.log(error);     
                           return false;
                            });
                    }

return {
                        load: function (widgetSettings) {
                            // Set your title
                            var $title = $('h2.title');
                            $title.text('Hello World');

                            var r1= getQueryInfo(widgetSettings);
                            var r2=getAnOhterQueryInfo(widgetSettings);
                            if(r1==true && r2==true){
                                return WidgetHelpers.WidgetStatusHelper.Success();
                             }else{

                           return WidgetHelpers.WidgetStatusHelper.Failure("failed, check error in console");
                        }
                    }
```

Comment: Thank you v much, I found something that unblocked me yesterday but I hate it when I feel like just hacking around, much obliged